# Python: Strange behavior of datetime.astimezone with respect to US/Pacific and America/Los_Angeles time zones?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

Please, observe:

```
C:\dev\poc\SDR>python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Nov 27 2010, 17:19:03) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pytz import timezone
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> tz1=timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
>>> tz2=timezone('US/Pacific')
>>> ts1=datetime(2011,8,1,tzinfo=tz1)
>>> ts2=datetime(2011,8,1,tzinfo=tz2)
>>> ts1
datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Los_Angeles' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>)
>>> ts2
datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>)
>>> ts1.astimezone(tz1)
datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Los_Angeles' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>)
>>> ts2.astimezone(tz2)
datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>)
>>> ts1.astimezone(tz2)
datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 1, 1, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific' PDT-1 day, 17:00:00 DST>)
>>> ts2.astimezone(tz1)
datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 1, 1, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Los_Angeles' PDT-1 day, 17:00:00 DST>)
>>>
```

Here is what I do not understand. US/Pacific (`tz1`) and America/Los_Angeles (`tz2`) are supposed to denote the same time zone, aren't they? Then how come that `datetime.astimezone` called to move from one zone to another changes the hour?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daylight Savings Time. Notice that the last two entries are listing `PDT-1`.

`astimezone` takes into account DST, but only if it actually goes through its full logic.

The first two `astimezone` calls in your example *don't* go through the full logic, because they short-circuit (since the timezone they're converting "to" already matches the one they're converting "from").

(You might wonder why the initial datetimes aren't using PDT already. This is because the `datetime` constructor [doesn't take into account daylight savings time](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic), even if you pass it a timezone - it just sets the timezone blindly.)

Comment: If you look at the prints, you can also see where it says 16:00:00 STD and 17:00:00 DST .

Comment: Thanks. How do you advise to construct a datetime object given a naive time value and a time zone?

Comment: @mark - as mentioned in the linked page, to convert a naive `datetime` to a localized one, use the `.localize()` method of the timezone object. (Basically, construct a `datetime` object without passing a `tzinfo`, then use the timezone object from `pytz` to localize it.)

Comment: Thanks, I have reread the docs again. Right, everything is there. Thanks again.